# C++11: 'make_shared' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++11, make-shared

I'm trying to update some of my code, and tried to include `make_shared`.

I created a class called Mail to send Emails, now i tried to include it:

```
    auto m =  std::make_shared<Mail>();
```

The issue is that I'm using a Makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
SYSTEM = $(shell uname)
C++ = g++
CC = gcc
DFLAGS = -DGHOST_MYSQL
OFLAGS = -O3
LFLAGS = -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lgmp
CFLAGS = -std=c++0x
```

The compile has this flag also included:

```
g++ -o mail.o -std=c++0x -O3 mail.cpp
```

But im getting the following error:

```
error: 'make_shared' is not a member of 'std'
  auto m =  std::make_shared<Mail>();
            ^
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
  auto m =  std::make_shared<Mail>();
                                 ^
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  auto m =  std::make_shared<Mail>();
                                   ^
make: *** [ghost.o] Error 1
```

What did I wrong here?

Comment: 1) What's the version of your compiler? and 2) did you `#include <memory>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`make_shared` needs you to [`#include <memory>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

I have no idea why you're looking at your Makefile for this... ?:-)

Comment: Oh my god, thats kinda awkward :X Thanks, that was the point :D